# cpp calling super constructors in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Mammal {
    public:
        int age;
        Mammal() {age = 55;}

        void say() {
            cout << "I'm a Mammal and my age " << age;
        }
};
class Reptile {
    public:
        int age;
        Reptile() {age = 77;}

        void say() {
            cout << "I'm a Reptile and my age " << age;
        }
};

class Platypus: public Mammal, public Reptile {
    public:
        Platypus() :
            Mammal(), Reptile() {
            cout << "Constructed!" << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Platypus p;
    p.Mammal::say();
    p.Reptile::say();
}
```

And result is:

```
I'm a Mammal and my age 4215460
I'm a Reptile and my age 4215472
```

Why:
1. `Platypus` constructor wasn't called and "Constructor" wasn't output?
2. `age`s in parents are still random (parent constructors wasn't called too?)

Comment: well, [it says so...](http://ideone.com/2oRyf1)

Comment: what compiler are you using? and that `Mammal()` and `Reptile()` initializer is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: awesome.... i'm using minGW

Comment: Compiles and runs as expected with g++.

Comment: Compiles and runs as expected with MinGW g++ 4.7.2. Which version are you using?

Comment: gcc 4.8.1.
seems the problem was in Eclipse admitted to my mistake. Sorry to have disturbed you.

Comment: @staticx `Mammal() and Reptile() initializer is unnecessary in this case` they will be called automatically?

Comment: Yup, try it. They will be called.

Comment: This can't be your real code; you don't send any newlines to `cout`, but there is a newline in your purported output.

Comment: @MattMcNabb it's real, but `endl`'s are realy missing)

Comment: You always need to provide the actual code to get a reliable answer.